# Wifi issues after installation on Lenovo Y700

Tags: dual-boot

So I was able to successfully install Ubuntu 15.10 However I have run into the error of having no WiFi. The ethernet cable works but it seems that the wifi is not possible to reach. This is my network adapter...i believe

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
Kernel driver in use: iwiwifi
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you think your adapter is Broadcom? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: And did you install updates using the Ethernet?

Comment: which updates would that be?

Comment: All updates. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Your adapter is supported. Unless it is blocked by rfkill.

Comment: I did exactly that and still after i disconnect my ethernet theres no wifi

Comment: I asked you to provide some output, but you ignored it.

Comment: Oh im sorry i didnt see that comment one moment

Comment: @Pilot6 sorry for missing your comment but there it is the output for rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wireless adapter is hardware blocked by rfkill, because of a tricky Lenovo UEFI firmware.

This issue has been fixed in upstream kernels, but the fix did not reach Ubuntu yet.

You can fix it by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

Reboot and enjoy.

When you upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04, remove this config by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
```

But likely the fix will reach the Ubuntu 4.2 kernel too.

Comment: When i typed the code in i was prompted for my password and after entering my password terminal just became stuck on the line after the password prompt line

Comment: You probably missed the closing `"`. Just try again and be more careful. You can cancel by Ctrl+C.

Comment: I have a Lenovo ideapad Y700 with Ubuntu 16.04 that was having similar issues and this answer worked great for me!

Answer (score -1):

There are two main driver packages for Broadcom networking hardware.  One is "firmware-b43-installer" and the other is "bcmwl-kernel-source".  At this point you should reference this post:
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers).  It has a nice table that someone has put together to show you how to identify your Broadcom chip's PCI.ID number, and which driver you will need based on what chip you have.  Don't worry if your chip doesn't show up, you can always just try one driver, and if it doesn't work, remove it and try the other.

**Gain Inetnet access (if possible):**

The first thing to do is to try to gain access to the Internet via a wire.  If you can plug up to your modem|router and gain access to Ubuntu.com then it will make your life much easier by avoiding the whole catch-22 section at the end of this post.

**Installing the bcmwl-kernel-source package:**

1. If you cannot gain Internet access via wire, then insert your Ubuntu installation media.  The required package should be available on the install media.
2. Open a new terminal window (control+alt+T)
3. Type: `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`
4. Type: `sudo reboot`

If that worked for you, then you're good to go and can stop here.  If that didn't work, or if the hardware seems flaky after you use it for a while, then you'll need to remove the bcmwl-kernel-source package before continuing on with these instructions:

1. Open a new terminal window (control+alt+T)
2. Type: `sudo dpkg --purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
3. Type: `sudo reboot`

**Installing the firmware-b43-installer package:**

NOTE: Installing this package *requires* Inetnet access.  There is a Broadcom firmware file needed by the installer that is *not* available on the Ubuntu install media.  If you can plug up to your modem|router by wire and surf the Internet then you're golden.  Otherwise you've got a catch-22 situation, and you'll have to stop here and skip down to the catch-22 section below.

If you DO have network access via wire:

1. Open a new terminal window (control+alt+T)
2. Type: `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
3. type: `sudo reboot`

If you can get online and everything seems stable, then great.  You can stop here.  Otherwise, if, for whatever reason, you decide to go back to the bcmwl-kernel-source package, then you'll first need to remove the firmware-b43-installer package before proceeding:

1. Open a new terminal window (control+alt+T)
2. Type: `sudo dpkg --purge firmware-b43-installer`
3. Type: `sudo reboot`

**Catch-22:**

If you're in the unlucky situation of being one of the few users who cannot get online via wifi nor wire, then you'll have to get your hands dirty to continue.  I have a full set of instructions written up that can guide you through replicating by hand what the firmware-b43-installer package would have done for you, but apparently it "looks like spam", so I wasn't able to post it.  Let me know if you wind up in this nasty situation and I'll see if I can post it somewhere else.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment i will definetly try it. And i do have access to the internet via ethernet so i will try the first two methods

Comment: So i had the bcmwl package installed but on reboot wifi still wasnt working. So i purged it and installed b43 however the package was read but it gave me E:UNABLE TO LOCATED PACKAGE and i did in fact type it in correctly

Comment: Your wireless adapter IS NOT BROADCOM. So this answer is not relevant at all.